# Gradle Build Exception after deleting spring-workspace and then creating new workspace with name spring-workspace-new

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite

I did a lot of search on  Stackoverflow before asking this question.

I'm using Spring Tool Suite and it is Java/Spring project. I deleted spring-workspace directory files by mistake.

Now, I created a new workspace with the name 'spring-workspace-new'  and imported my all projects in Spring Tool Suite.

On building them, it is showing error: "**Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build**".  Along with that showing multiple exception like:

1. `org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution`
2. Caused by: `org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'project name'`
3. Caused by: `org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'project name'`
4. Caused by: `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:` Could not resolve all files for configuration
5. `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.alight.gradle:ah-gradle-plugins:1.+.`

If you know any solution, please let me know. If you need more information, I can share that.

Comment: I don't know the direct answer to this problem, but it vaguely looks like the Gradle build has issues resolving some artifacts. Does the Gradle build from the command line works? Maybe delete the local artifact cache and try again? Just some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the problem.

I just switched back to develop branch for all project modules, took "git pull" and then did Gradle refresh.

It solved the problem.